# Error al instalar módulo (__ngcc_entry_points__.json)

Tags: angular, ionic, npm

Estoy intentando instalar nuevos módulos en un desarrollo ionic.
Al lanzar el npm install del módulo, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "__ngcc_entry_points__.json": name cannot start with an underscore
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Prueba a borrar node_modules y volver a hacer npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Trata con borrar node_modules, verifica que el package.json tenga un formato correcto.

Puedes validar tu package [aqui](http://package-json-validator.com/).

Al final vuelve a instalar con `npm install` o `npm i`.